# Multivariable chain rule derivative definition calculation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

How can we calculate such expressions, in particular:

Let $f,g$ be both diffrentiable, how to calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x(t) +hg(x(t)), y(t)+h\frac{dg}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}) -f(x(t), y(t) )}h\ $$

Comment: Show us what you’ve done and ask a specific question where you are stuck.

Comment: I kinda know the answer, but I wanted a rigorous justification for it. Intuitively we can treat it as a directional derevitive problem and use that formula. But the problem is that the formula for directional derevitive that I'm familiar with is derived on a function of independent variables. The function in my question is a function of functions, so I'm not sure how to make my argument rigorous in treating both situations the same.

Comment: $t$ is fixed, so it is just that.